# Route issue with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have `photos#new` with this path

`/:profile_name/photos/new(.:format)`

I want to create a route to `/photos/upload` for that path above (`photos#new`).

I'm trying this:

```
scope '/photos/upload' do
 scope ':profile_name' do
  resources :photos, only: [:new, :create], as: 'upload_photo'
 end
end
```

but I get the error:

```
undefined method `upload_photo_path'
```

how can I do this route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of these `scope`s make any sense.

Just define a route.

```
get "photos/upload" => "photos#new"
```

Comment: show this error: `No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"photos", :format=>nil, :profile_name=>nil} missing required keys: [:profile_name]`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
scope '/photos/upload' do
 scope ':profile_name' do
  resources :photos, only: [:new, :create], as: 'upload_photo'
 end
end
```

with this

```
scope ':profile_name' do
  resources :photos, only: [:new, :create]
end

get "photos/upload" => "photos#new", as: 'upload_photo'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resources**

Further to the answers already, you should be aware that Rails works with a [`resourceful` routing structure](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default). Whilst this is not a direct fix, it *should* give you a better idea as to how to construct your routes:

[image]

Simply, *every* route you create should be tied to a "resource". Each "resource" is essentially a way for you to build model objects -- typically a controller, although you may use different controllers to create different model objects

--

**Routes**

This means that your `photos` resource should be the primary focus of your routes; if you want to add an extra route, or change the name of one of the resourceful routes, you should do it *around* the `resources` directive:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :photos, path_names: { new: "upload" } #-> domain.com/photos/upload
```

You can see I used the [`path_names` argument as per this documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-new-and-edit-segments)

Resource scopes are generally used if you have modules, or subdirectory-based controllers (they provide another level to your routes). And if you wanted to add extra routes to your `resources` directive, you can use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :photos do
   collection do
      get :upload, action: new
   end
end
```